# document.getElementByClassName is doen't work properly

Tags: javascript

```
$('.inlineDatepickerDepart').datepick({ minDate: '<%=@start_display%>', maxDate: '<%=@end_display%>',
   monthsToShow: 2,
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  onSelect: function(date) {
```

var selected=parseInt(document.getElementById("guest_adult").value)+parseInt(document.getElementById("guest_kid").value);
  alert(selected);

```
for(var x=0;x<selected;x++)
{
document.getElementsByClassName("depart1")[x].innerHTML = '2012-03-24';
document.getElementsByClassName("return1")[x].innerHTML = '2012-04-24';
}
},
});
```

The alert shows the no of guests.It replaces value of depart1[0] alone.Not for the entire loop and 'return1' class too. can any one give me key to solve it

Comment: Please show your html. And as an aside, be careful with `parseInt()`: you should be supplying the radix in the second parameter, especially if using it on user-entered values. (So `parseInt(someValue, 10)`, not `parseInt(someValue)`.)

Comment: ok.i just give values manually like for(var x=0;x<3;x++) and selects only 3 adults and o kids. Now also it shows same problem.I think the problem is not in parseInt

Comment: I didn't say the problem was with `parseInt()`, I was simply providing some general `parseInt()` advice "as an aside". If you want help with your actual problem please show (at least an extract of) your html.

Comment: @nnnnnn Please check my edited question.i am beginner to javascript.let me to figure out the mistake i made

Comment: So where is the html for the "depart1" and "return1" elements? We need to see the html to help you. (And is that datepick code jQuery? If so, why not use jQuery to update your elements?)

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for your comments.At last i got answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works by using following codes.

```
var a;
var b;
for(var x=0;x<selected;x++)
{
a=document.getElementsByClassName("depart1")[x];
a.innerHTML = depart_date;
b=document.getElementsByClassName("return1")[x];
b.innerHTML = return_date;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to catch basic errors, like the fact the `getElementByClassName` function doesn't exist.

Use [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) instead.

Comment: i Used getElementsByClassName.but it replaces value for first depart[0] alone.not working for remaining loop

Comment: No : **you** should build a fiddle demonstrating your problem, with minimal HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It's plural:

```
document.getElementsByClassName
                   ^
```

Comment: i Used plural(getElementsByClassName).but it replaces value for first depart[0] alone.

Answer (score 2):

You should use :

```
getElementsByClassName
```

Because there can be more than one elements with same class applied so it's plural.